# Read properties file at client side in gwt mvp4g 

Tags: gwt, mvp4g

I am using Mvp4g in gwt and i want to read properties file but if  i add resourcebundle  code its giving me exception 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mvp4g.client.Mvp4gModule' (did you forget to inherit a required module?) 
but if i remove resourcebundle code its working fine . Is there any way to do that.

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.opptin.client.socialsite");
String siteUrl = rb.getString("mode");
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.ResourceBundle` is not supported by the GWT compiler (if you want to know which Java APIs are emulated, have a look at the [JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation)).

To use properties on the GWT client side, you can use [com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants](https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.html). An alternative is to pick JavaScript variables directly from the host page by [com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary](https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html).

Comment: maybe i am wrong.. but is there any way where i can define a properties file and read it through GWT because i have many properties in my properties file...  :(

Comment: You don't want to define a method for every property, correct? I think this is only possible with `Dictionary`. You could make your GWT host page dynamic and write the properties from the file to javascript variables on the page. But the dot-notation of your property keys may cause problems.